# Git merge separation

Tags: git

The biggest problem I noticed in a merge is the fact that in the end you end up with a single commit.

Is there a way you can separated after a conflict merge the automated merged files and the manual fixed files ( 2 separate commits ) ?

Comment: Why would this be useful?  You can determine which files needed conflict resolution by performing the merge again.

Comment: The default commit message will contain a list of conflicted files.

Comment: some files will be merged automatically if it's possible

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so it would be nice if you could accept the answer if it helped or provide your own so other people could benefit from the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters pointed out the files requiring the conflict resolution are going to be listed in the default commit message, so there seems to be no point in such separation. in Addition to that you actually don't want to have two commits, because one of them will reflect partial merge of two branches, i.e. reflect the results of the process that was not finished yet.

You should note that Git commit being atomic is reflecting the state of the whole repository. It seems that you're thinking about that through CVS experience, where commits are not atomic. Git doesn't track files as CVS does, therefore merge separation like you describing is not suitable for Git.

If you want more granular control of the conflicts you should then use rebase instead of merge.